# Visual Studio 2017 - Get Information about running tasks

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I have the problem, that I'm trying to perform a check whether an internet connection is available.

I am using this code snippet:

```
public void tasks()
{
  log.Add("LOG - Check for InternetConnection");      //log
  DialogResult result = new DialogResult();
  while (!InternetConnection())       //Check for Interent Connection
  {
    result = MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection Detected!\nPlease Connect to Internet and Retry", "ERROR - No Internet Connection", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
      break;
    }
  }
  if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
  {
    Application.Exit();
  }
}

#region CheckInternetConnection
[DllImport("wininet.dll")]
private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int Description, int ReservedValue);

private bool InternetConnection()
{
  log.Add("LOG - InternetConnection called");     //log
  try
  {
    int Description;
    return InternetGetConnectedState(out Description, 0);
  }
  catch       //Not connected
  {
    log.Add("LOG - No Internet Connection");    //log
    return false;
  }
}
#endregion CheckInternetConnection
```

My problem is that, while `Application.Exit()` gets executed (I checked by setting Breakpoints) the Application runs right past that line.

As of my understanding, this is caused by a task running in the background.

So I want to know whether it is possible to get information about the tasks running...

As you may probably know by now I am using Visual Studio 2017 and have a Windows Forms Application.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, Application.Exit() close all tasks. Try with Enviroment.Exit().

Comment: @FelipeDeveza Thanks! It works like a charm! If you would be so kind to post it as a proper answer I would be thankful to give you some rep for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Application.Exit() close all tasks.

Try with:

```
Enviroment.Exit()
```